Tahara for drowning in Mikveh
Is a Tahara performed if one drowned (Chas V'Sholom) while immersed in a Mikveh/ocean?

The common case of this is drowning in an ocean or lake (indeed the vast vast majority of drowning cases classically)

@DoubleAA "while immersed in a Mikveh" seems to imply unclothed, maybe Moshe will clear up his intention

@Nahum No clue where you are seeing that, but anyway the most common case of naked drowning (?) historically was surely in an ocean/lake as well.

Yes I meant to say that the person drowning is unclothed, presumably immersed fully.

The Shach and Taz on YD 364:4 write that tahara is performed for those who drown in water but the minhag might be different
Shach (end of 364:11) based on Maharil

מי שנטבע במים בבגדיו דפושטין בגדיו ומטהרין אותו ומלבישין אותו תכריכין
וכמ"ש בסוף ספר מהרי"ל ע"כ

The Taz (end of 364:3) quotes the same Maharil but adds the minhag is to bury them clothed

וכתב עוד דמי שמת מחמת קור ושלג או נטבע במים בבגדיו דפושטין בגדיו
ומטהרין אותו ומלבישין אותו בתכריכין ע"כ. והמנהג לקבור בבגדים הנמצאים
נטבעים


The question was regarding one that drowned sans clothing

@Nahum I don't see that in the question

@DoubleAA It is strongly implied

@Nahum in which words?
